# Antlr4 grammar compilation error

Tags: java, antlr4, chess

I made my own chess PGN grammar for ANTLR4, but I get a java stacktrace error :

Pgn.g4 grammar :

```
grammar Pgn;

file:       game (NEWLINE+ game)*;
game:       (tag+ NEWLINE+)? notation;

tag:        '['TAG_TYPE "TAG_VALUE"']';
notation: move+ END_RESULT?;
move:   MOVE_NUMBER\. MOVE_DESC MOVE_DESC       #CompleteMove
        |   MOVE_NUMBER\. MOVE_DESC             #OnlyWhiteMove
        |   MOVE_NUMBER\.\.\. MOVE_DESC         #OnlyBlackMove
        ;

END_RESULT: '1-0'
            | '0-1'
            | '1/2-1/2'
            ;

TAG_TYPE:   LETTER+;
TAG_VALUE:  .*;

MOVE_NUMBER: DIGIT+;
MOVE_DESC: .*;  

NEWLINE:    \r? \n;
SPACES:     [ \t]+ -> skip;

fragment LETTER: [a-zA-Z];
fragment DIGIT: [0-9];
```

And this is the error output :

```
$ antlr4 Pgn.g4 
org\antlr\v4\parse\GrammarTreeVisitor.g: node from line 24:11 required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input 'r'
org\antlr\v4\parse\GrammarTreeVisitor.g: node from line 24:15 mismatched tree node: n expecting <UP>
org\antlr\v4\parse\GrammarTreeVisitor.g: node from line 24:11 required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input 'r'
org\antlr\v4\parse\GrammarTreeVisitor.g: node from line 24:15 mismatched tree node: n expecting <UP>
org\antlr\v4\parse\GrammarTreeVisitor.g: node from line 24:11 required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input 'r'
org\antlr\v4\parse\GrammarTreeVisitor.g: node from line 24:15 mismatched tree node: n expecting <UP>
org\antlr\v4\parse\GrammarTreeVisitor.g: node from line 24:11 required (...)+ loop did not match anything at input 'r'
org\antlr\v4\parse\GrammarTreeVisitor.g: node from line 24:15 mismatched tree node: n expecting <UP>
error(20):  internal error: Rule LETTER undefined 
error(20):  internal error: element list has first|last == null 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.antlr.v4.automata.ParserATNFactory.elemList(ParserATNFactory.java:445)
    at org.antlr.v4.automata.ParserATNFactory.alt(ParserATNFactory.java:414)
    at org.antlr.v4.parse.ATNBuilder.alternative(ATNBuilder.java:567)
    at org.antlr.v4.parse.ATNBuilder.block(ATNBuilder.java:400)
    at org.antlr.v4.parse.ATNBuilder.subrule(ATNBuilder.java:1185)
    at org.antlr.v4.parse.ATNBuilder.element(ATNBuilder.java:887)
    at org.antlr.v4.parse.ATNBuilder.alternative(ATNBuilder.java:550)
    at org.antlr.v4.parse.ATNBuilder.ruleBlock(ATNBuilder.java:289)
    at org.antlr.v4.automata.ParserATNFactory._createATN(ParserATNFactory.java:148)
    at org.antlr.v4.automata.LexerATNFactory.createATN(LexerATNFactory.java:94)
    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.processNonCombinedGrammar(Tool.java:407)
    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.process(Tool.java:376)
    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.processGrammarsOnCommandLine(Tool.java:343)
    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.main(Tool.java:190)
```

So, what's the problem with my grammar ?

(Notice that this post can be a step further the one I exposed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20759138/error-when-generating-a-grammar-for-chess-pgn-files), where I had a syntax error).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things are going wrong:

---

> ```
> tag:        '['TAG_TYPE "TAG_VALUE"']';
> ```

Why are there double quotes around `TAG_VALUE`? Remove the quotes if you want to match the token `TAG_VALUE`: `tag:        '['TAG_TYPE TAG_VALUE ']';`

---

> ```
> MOVE_NUMBER\. MOVE_DESC MOVE_DESC
> ```

If you want to match the literal `.` (DOT) you need to put quotes around it (and not escape it!): `MOVE_NUMBER '.' MOVE_DESC MOVE_DESC`

---

> ```
> NEWLINE:    \r? \n;
> ```

Again, if you want to match the literals, put quotes around it: `NEWLINE:    '\r'? '\n';`

---

> ```
> TAG_VALUE: .*;  
> ...
> MOVE_DESC: .*;
> ```

Those rule will gobble up your entire input stream. You need another way to match a tag value and move description than you do now. Do not use `.*`.

### EDIT

Here’s an existing PGN grammar: https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/pgn

Comment: Thank you very much. For the "TAG_VALUE", I wanted to catch some contents inside double quotes without fetching them into my TAG_VALUE lexer. Now, the other big point will be to avoid the two wilcard (.*): as I wanted to match any printable character, including spaces.

Comment: I found [:print:] for printable characters : now need a way to avoid those double quotes around TAG_VALUE ... again without catching them.